# Detect deadlock between a group of goroutines

Tags: go, deadlock

Golang can detect deadlocks when all goroutines are stuck. But is it possible to detect if a group of goroutines are stuck? For example in the following code goroutine 1 and 2 will be in a deadlock but the program continues working because the main goroutine is not stuck. My question is how can I detect that goroutine 1 and 2 as a group are in a deadlock because all members of the group are stuck?

```
func main() {
    ch1 := make(chan int)
    ch2 := make(chan int)

    // goroutine 1
    go func() {
        ch1 <- 12
        ch2 <- 13 // oh oh, wrong channel. deadlock between goroutine 1 and 2
    }()

    // goroutine 2
    go func() {
        println(<-ch1)
        println(<-ch1)
    }()

    for {
        // i'm busy
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}
```

Comment: No, that is not computable in general. I'm not aware of any static analysis tools to detect this very specific case you've shown. It would be extremely unlikely to have a send on a channel and no receives on that channel anywhere in the program.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a special case of the [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem). Which is to say, there is no programmatic way to detect or predict a deadlock.

Comment: Elaborating on the situation a bit: How would you distinguish between a deadlock, and waiting for user input, or some other I/O operation? From the goroutine's perspective, there's no difference, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 5):

[pprof](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/pprof/) allows you to get a full goroutine stack dump at runtime, which will show you what goroutines are blocked and why. This isn't exactly what you describe, but it's enough information to see when a partial deadlock occurs. It also includes a dedicated block profiler for monitoring blocked goroutines.